# Add multiple tabs inside chrome.tabs.group()

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, complex-data-types

I cannot add multiple tabs inside one group tab with an array because it return this error :
[Uncaught TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYVtB.png)

Here's my code :

```
for (let group in result) {
//creating the group title and displaying it in the popup
let groupTitle = document.createElement("p");

groupTitle.style.setProperty(
  "--color",
  result[group][result[group].length - 1]
);
groupTitle.classList.add("groupTitle");

let tabsIds = [];
//opening the new tab when the text is click
groupTitle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < result[group].length - 1; i++) {
    //creating the new tabs one by one
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: result[group][i] }, async function (newTab) {
      tabsIds.push(newTab.id);
    });
  }
  
  //creating a group tab with the tab created
  let groupId = chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabsIds });
  //modifying the group tab
  chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, {
    collapsed: false,
    title: group,
    color: result[group][result[group].length - 1]
  });
});
groupsContainer.appendChild(groupTitle);
groupTitle.append(group);
}
});
```

I think it could come from the data types inside the array but I have no clue on how to solve it, so please I beg for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome` API methods that return a Promise or use a callback are asynchronous, so the result is returned after the current synchronous function completes.

You need to declare the function as `async` and use `await` on every call:

```js
groupTitle.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const tabsIds = [];
  for (const url of result[group]) {
    const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({url});
    tabsIds.push(tab.id);
  }
  const groupId = await chrome.tabs.group({tabIds: tabsIds});
  //chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, {...});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wOxxOm thanks a lot, here's my complete and working code in case somebody need it :

```
groupTitle.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < result[group].length - 1; i++) {
    //creating the new tabs one by one
    let tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ url: result[group][i] });
    tabsIds.push(tab.id);
  }
  
  //creating a group tab with the tab created
  let groupId = await chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds: tabsIds });
  //modifying the group tab
  await chrome.tabGroups.update(groupId, {
    collapsed: false,
    title: group,
    color: result[group][result[group].length - 1]
  });
});
```

Here I still use a classic for loop because the last index in my array is not a URL, so I need to stop the loop before the last one.
That's why I used `.length - 1`.

But if it was a URL it'll work perfectly as wOxxOm write it :-)